# "XML Parsing Error: no root element found" Ionic/Angular

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework

There are many topics with this similar error: "XML Parsing Error: no root element found", but none of them cover the error for Ionic framework.

I am writing an app with Ionic framework, and this is the function to POST the data:

**http.ts**

```
postData(url, body) {

const headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

const result = this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify(body), {headers: headers})
  .map(response => {
    console.log(response.json());
    response.json();
  })
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(typeof(data));
    console.log("subscribe data");
    },
  error => {
    console.log(error.statusText);
  })
```

A button on my app's HTML form calls the onSubmit function to send the data like below.

**submit.ts**

```
onSubmit() {

var submitData = {
    'customer': {
      'phone_number': this.clientInfo.phone,
      'name': this.clientInfo.name
    },
    'amount': this.clientInfo.amount
}



const submitResult = this.httpProvider.postData(postTransactionsURL, submitData);
```

Now, on Firefox, this is the error that is shown in the console:

> XML Parsing Error: no root element found
>   Location: http://localhost:3000/transactions
>   Line Number 1, Column 1:

As reported in other posts, the error does not show up on e.g. Edge, but nevertheless, there is still a more generic error.

Is there anything I could try to resolve this? I would assume the header is correct for this?

**Update: added POST network information from console:**

> Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
>   Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Content-Length: 0
>   Date: Fri, 02 Mar 2018 12:42:36 GMT
>   X-Powered-By: Express

**Update2: server.js response**

```
app.post('/transactions', (req, res) => {


 ......
 ......
 ......

    res.status(200).send();
    } else {
    res.status(400).send("Invalid transaction");
    }
 });
```

Comment: So where is XML involved here? I don’t see _any_ ...

Comment: My question too... No XML, just JSON...

Comment: Check what content `http://localhost:3000/transactions` returned in browser dev tools network panel.

Comment: @CBroe: Please see information update in topic post. Those are the response headers in the network console part.